# get max, min, avg values with other specific columns in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My table looks like this.

```
id | restaurant_id | user_id  | rating | comment 

1        1              2          3.5     comment1

2        1              2          2.1     comment2

3        1              2          4.1     comment3

4        1              2          1.6     comment4
```

Now, I have restaurant_id as 1. what I want is to get maximum rating(4.1) , minimum rating(1.6) and avg rating(whatever it is). I do that correctly, but I also want to get comment. something like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        max:{
            max_rating:4.1,
            comment:"comment 3",
            id: 3
        },

        min:{
            min_rating:1.6,
            comment: "comment 4",
            id: 4,
        }

        avg:{
            avg_rating:"whatever it is",
            //this won't have comment and id at all.
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried:

```
$data = \App\Http\Models\Review::select("id", "comment",DB::raw("MAX(rating) AS max_price, MIN(rating) AS min_price"))
        ->where("restaurant_id", 1)
        ->groupBy("id")
        ->get();
```

but doesn't work as i explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more straightforward solution is to do 3 separate queries:

```
$avg = Review::select(DB::raw('avg(rating) as avg_rating')
    ->where('restaurant_id', 1)
    ->groupBy('restaurant_id')
    ->get();

$max = Review::select('id','comment','rating')
    ->where('restaurant_id', 1)
    ->orderBy('rating','DESC')
    ->first();

$min = Review::select('id','comment','rating')
    ->where('restaurant_id', 1)
    ->orderBy('rating','ASC')
    ->first();

$json = json_encode(['data' => [
  'avg' => $avg,
  'max' => $max,
  'min' => $min
]]);
```

You could extract the max, min and average with a single query, but without including the id and the comment of the max/min:

```
$stats = Review::select(DB::raw('avg(rating) as avg_rating, max(rating) as max_rating, min(rating) as min_rating')
        ->where('restaurant_id', 1)
        ->groupBy('restaurant_id')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try these :

```
$average = \App\Http\Models\Review::where("restaurant_id", 1)->avg('rating');
$max = \App\Http\Models\Review::where("restaurant_id", 1)->max('rating');
$min = \App\Http\Models\Review::where("restaurant_id", 1)->min('rating');
```

If you need to calculate these values for many restaurants at the same time, the query written in your message would be a good start. What result does it give you instead of the values expected ?

Comment: `$max` and `$min` would not include the id and the comment, but those methods are great and I didn't know them. Thanks!

Comment: What result does it give you instead of the values expected ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get min, max, and average in one query Laravel

```
$stats=stats::where('userid',Auth::User()->id)->get();
    $min=$stats->min('point');
    $max=$stats->max('point');
    $avg=$stats->avg('point');
```